# Azure Graph query to get VM Agent status for all VMs

Tags: azure, graph, virtual-machine

I'm trying to get a query to check the VM Agent status in Azure. Currently I'm using RestAPI, but I need one call to the API for each machine, and I want to do it with Azure Graph to list all the VMs with the Azure Agent status in a single request.

This is the query in Azure Graph

```
Resources
| where type in~ ("microsoft.compute/virtualmachines","microsoft.classiccompute/virtualmachines")
```

But under properties the STATUS of the agent is not available. Any ideas?

I tried listing the extensions but it is also not helping, with this query:

```
Resources
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| extend
    JoinID = toupper(id),
    OSName = tostring(properties.osProfile.computerName),
    OSType = tostring(properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType),
    VMSize = tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize)
| join kind=leftouter(
    Resources
    | where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/extensions'
    | extend
        VMId = toupper(substring(id, 0, indexof(id, '/extensions'))),
        ExtensionName = name
) on $left.JoinID == $right.VMId
| summarize Extensions = make_list(ExtensionName) by id, OSName, OSType, VMSize
| order by tolower(OSName) asc
```

I can only see the extensions but I need the Azure Agent STATUS.

Comment: Instead of checking the agent status, you can easily check the VM status by projecting `powerstate`. If it works for you, I can provide you the solution.

Comment: Thanks, but the VM can be running, but the agent can be down. This means that any action/metrics for the VM will not work. This is why I need the agent status.
The other option that I have is the REST API, but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many approaches, Agent Status cannot be retrieved directly from the VM properties but ProvisioningState as well as powerstate can be retrieved.

> This ProvisionVMAgent property is there for marketplace images that have the agent installed on creation as mentioned [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/53186).

To identify the exact health check of the VM, we can use the "***ProvisioningState***" attribute rather than the "*Agent status*".

*I've done these changes to your code:*

```
Resources

| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| extend
JoinID = toupper(id),
OSName = tostring(properties.osProfile.computerName),
OSType = tostring(properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType),
VMSize = tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize),
powerState = tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.displayStatus),
ProvisioningState = tostring(properties.provisioningState)
| join kind=leftouter(
Resources
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/extensions'
| extend
VMId = toupper(substring(id, 0, indexof(id, '/extensions'))),
ExtensionName = name
) on  $left.JoinID == $right.VMId
| summarize Extensions = make_list(ExtensionName) by id, OSName, OSType, VMSize, powerState, ProvisioningState
| order  by tolower(OSName) asc
```

***Output:***

[image]

**Note**: *All statuses of VM's can be received by calling PowerShell command `Get-AzVM -status`*

*Reference*: [AzureVMAgent](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e0beb3c-64d9-4623-b65a-6a26f7f27b65/detect-azure-vm-agent-in-linux-vms#:%7E:text=Programatically%2C%20you%20can%20query%20the%20VM%20Agent%20status,Agent%20status%20all%20VMs%20across%20all%20subscriptions%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fcap273%2FAzure-PowerShell%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2FAzureVMAgentAudit.ps1), [Finding VM Agent-Powershell](https://rakhesh.com/azure/azure-finding-vm-agent-version/)
given by @rakhesh sasidharan

Comment: Thank you for the help and the work that you did to find a solution. But this is not what Im looking for.

Comment: Thanks! what exactly are you looking for? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: "Provisioning state" describes VM health well. Thats why I provided the same instead of VMAgent status.